# Flutter Android build fails with 'AAPT: error: attribute 'android:name' in <application> tag must be a valid Java class name.'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, aapt

I upgraded to the latest Flutter version.

Afterwards it started giving the error...

```
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Warning
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project. You may also pass the --ignore-deprecation flag to
ignore this check and continue with the deprecated v1 embedding. However,
the v1 Android embedding will be removed in future versions of Flutter.
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
The detected reason was:

  /myAppPath/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FutterApplication"`
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding.
```

I then went to the migration guide and implemented the required changes which were changing the first line to the second

```
-android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
+android:name="@{applicationName}"
```

Now I get the error...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /pathToMyApp/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-51:19: AAPT: error: attribute 'android:name' in <application> tag must be a valid Java class name.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           41.9s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this

```
android:name="${applicationName}"
```

instead of

```
android:name="@{applicationName}"
```

Comment: Where to do this?

Comment: in AndroidMenifest.xml file